# javascript function default prototype vs Object instance

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance

What is the relationship between Function.prototype and the Object instance?

```
function Person() {}
var obj = new Object();
console.dir(Person.prototype);
console.dir(obj);
```

the console result is:
[image]

My question:

What happened behind while `function Person() {}` run? How the constructor function added to Person.prototype?

Comment: `someFunction.prototype.constructor == someFunction`. the result of calling that function is the default prototype for an instance made with that constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one can be answered by looking at the EMCAScript standard

First, look at the `new` keyword, documented here:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2

which in turn calls the internal `[[Construct]]` method, documented here:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2

*Step 7*: Set the [[Construct]] internal property of F as described in 13.2.2.